# Size of automorphism group of finite Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I have seen that if an extension is finite and Galois then the size of the automorphism group is equal to the degree of the extension - but is the converse always true? Ie if I have an extension and find that the size of the automorphism group is equal to the degree of the extension then can I immediately say that the extension is Galois?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's true : in general you have $|Gal(L/K)| \leqslant [L:K]_s \leqslant [L:K]$ (where $[L:K]_s$ is the separable degree).

The first one is an equality iff $L/K$ is normal, and the second one is an equality iff $L/K$ is separable.

So the "big" inequality is an equality iff $L/K$ is Galois.

Comment: So if I have $\mathbb{Q}(\xi)/ \mathbb{Q}$ where $\xi$ is the p-th root of unity (p is an odd prime) then the minimal polynomial is $x^{p-1}+...+x+1$ hence  $[\mathbb{Q}(\xi): \mathbb{Q}]=p-1$   But the roots of the minimal polynomial are $\xi, \xi^2, ..., \xi^{p-1}$ which are all contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\xi)$ thus are all K-conjugates and so we have p-1 possible conjugate values and so p-1 automorphisms Hence $|Aut\mathbb{Q}(\xi)/ \mathbb{Q}| =[\mathbb{Q}(\xi): \mathbb{Q}]$  And so the extension is Galois?

Comment: This proof is not really incorrect, but you should rather invoke the fact that an extension is Galois iff it's the splitting field of a separable polynomial, which is more fundamental in my opinion.

Comment: It's a splitting field for $x^{p-1} + \cdots + x + 1 \in \Bbb Q[x]$, so yes, it's Galois.